# How to integrate an existing html page into a react-app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, frontend

We have created a static site using html templates found online. The site contains one dynamic page for data display. We have now created a react app to build this dynamic page. How can we now include the existing html files into this react app?

Comment: Make different components according to you site and where dynamic data needed, use JSX

Comment: You can use webview, it supports local file. But.....you'll see a lot of links to fix. Else host it and view with webview. But why not do a website, if you publish in Apple's T&C that's the first question to need to bypass for doing such app.

Comment: I think what do you need is the reverse as the dynamic page is part of the site 
and you embed it in static HTML  as that  https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-cache-m783n?file=/public/index.html

Comment: what we have tried now is to just copy our html files and css files etc into the public folder. When we build the site it works but what we want to do is change the name of the dynamic site so that react makes a different html file with a different name not equal to index.html so we can navigate to this file from our landing page. If we do this now and we build the app react still opens its own dynamic site instead of our index.html landing page. Im new to react btw